# Implementing Sub-Row in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to implement a sub-row (details) functionality in ag-grid. The purpose of this would be to show additional details for each row when the user clicks on a down arrow, by opening a section of custom content under the main row. I am looking for suggestions on how best to implement this in ag-grid for react.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [Master Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/).

Comment: thanks, Viqas. That's exactly what I need but I don't have the option to go for enterprise license.